# How do I delete all rows in a table which have a null foreign key reference?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, A and B. A has a column `B_Id` which references the `Id` column of table B.

There are a number of rows in table A that have a value for `B_Id`, but that value does not exist anywhere in the list of Ids of table B.

I want to delete all of these particular rows.

I've tried

```
select * from A left join B on A.B_Id = B.Id where B.Id = null
```

But this doesn't select anything at all. How can I change the select to retrieve the rows I want?

Comment: NULLs aren't equal to anything, even NULLs. This means that `B.Id = null` is *always* false.

Comment: Just to "nit pick" a little, but `B.Id = null` isn't *false*, @PanagiotisKanavos , it's *unknown*. This means it isn't true, but it also isn't false. This is an important distiction as neither `B.Id = null` or `NOT (B.Id = null)` evaluate to true (if `B.Id = null` were *false* the latter would). From a boolean expression where testing for true, *unknown* is "as good as" *false* but *unknown* is still a different distinct result to `*true* and *false*.

Answer (score 3):

`NOT EXISTS` comes to mind:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.b_id);
```

You can easily incorporate this into a `delete` if you want to remove the rows:

```
delete from a
    where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.b_id);
```

BUT . . . you should really fix the problem moving forward by putting in a proper constraints.  You seem to want a `NOT NULL` constraint and a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

Answer (score 2):

You need `where b.id is null` rather than `where b.id = null`. In SQL, nothing is equal to `null` (nor different than `null`): to compare against `null`, you need special construct `is [not] null`.

I think that this is simpler expressed with `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.b_id)
```

If you wanted a `delete` statement:

```
delete from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.b_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `IS` operator, like

```
select * from A left join B on A.B_Id = B.Id where B.Id is null
```

the reason is that null is unkown and the language isn't certain whether something is equal to it or not. You can also do it via `not exists` as Gordon Linoff has already pointed out.

Whatever you try, make sure that you make a full backup of your table.

If `B_Id` is already a `foreign key` and `foreign key` checking is enabled for your database, then you can safely assume that every record that has no pair in B has a `B_Id` of null in A, which renders the join and checking for existence unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the data you want to delete with

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE B_ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM B);
```

To delete these rows just use this

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE B_ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM B);
```

Comment: Considering the OP infers that `B` will have a value of `NULL` this isn't going to work as you expect. When dealing with `NULL` values `NOT IN` should be avoided as it **not** work the way you expect. For example `SELECT 1 WHERE 1 NOT IN (SELECT I FROM (VALUES(2),(3),(4),(5),(NULL))V(I));` returns no rows, despite that `1` is not in the `VALUES` clause. This behaviour is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#result-value) in the big orange **Caution** box.